# Run a terminal script to get the apple ID from the localhost?

Tags: terminal, icloud, apple-id

I'm trying to get the appleID account that is logged into the iCloud account of a MacOS computer.

I've tried with

```
defaults export MobileMeAccounts 

dscl . -list /Users UniqueID

Defaults find  SHKRecentServices
```

I will run this command on multiple computers to run an audit but I get it to work only on my personal one.